# while using map<String,Arraylist<String>> in java jersey api it is only giving key of map i.e String

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

while hitting below method only key of map which is 'name' is coming in response .....
why value of map which is ArrayList is not coming in response

endpoint of mehtod is as below

```
    public LoginResponse LoginUserJSON(LoginRequestVO requestVOLogin)
    {
    LoginResponse lr = new LoginResponse();
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapObj = new 
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> loginRequestVOs = new ArrayList<>();

    lr.setStatus("Done");
    loginRequestVOs.add("parth1");
    loginRequestVOs.add("parth2");

    mapObj.put("name", loginRequestVOs);

    lr.setRequestData(mapObj);

    System.out.println(mapObj);
    return lr;
    }
```

responsevo is as below

```
    @XmlRootElement(name= "Response")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class LoginResponse
    {
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    String status;

    @XmlElement(name = "requestData")
    private  Map<String, ArrayList<String>> requestData;

    public String getStatus()
    {
    return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
    this.status = status;
    }

    public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> getRequestData()
    {
    return requestData;
    }

    public void setRequestData(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> requestData)
    {
    this.requestData = requestData;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try out the stream api if you are using java 8

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapObj = new HashMap<>();

mapObj.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> String.format("[key: %s, value: %s]", entry.getKey(), Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().toArray())))
    .forEach(System.out::println)
;
```